# Requirements and inputvalidation

Tags: xifthen

I want to recreate my current makros to work in every document. Currently I am working on the task, if a package is loaded, the command will be provided as desired.

Look at the following MWE, which works as expected.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\newboolean{pkglddebug}
\setboolean{pkglddebug}{true}

\newboolean{pkgldxcolor}
\setboolean{pkgldxcolor}{false}

\providecommand{\pkgldxcolortxt}{Package xcolor not loaded or missing}

% Comment this package in or out to see what will happen.
% \usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}%
            {
            \setboolean{pkgldxcolor}{true}
            \renewcommand{\pkgldxcolortxt}{Package loaded}
            }
            {           
            }
\makeatother


\ifthenelse{\boolean{pkgldxcolor}}%
    {%  
    \providecommand{\test}[1]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}}
    }
    {
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{pkglddebug}}%
        {%
        \providecommand{\test}[1]{Need Package xcolor}
        }
        {
        }
    \providecommand{\test}[1]{\textbf{#1}} % or \providecommand{\test}{} if you don't want to access anything
    \providecommand{\textcolor}[2]{Sorry, xcolor not loaded, you tried to make #2 in color #1}
    }


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \test{A}
\item \textcolor{red}{text}
\item \pkgldxcolortxt
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

If you comment out xcolor, the example still compiles. If you set the debugflag, you will see, why the command wont work as expected.

This is a very primitive example of check if package is loaded and tell the command how to work.

My question: Is there any better way to achieve this solution?
Second question would be, if there is any nice way of inputvalidation for commands like

```
\providecommand{\mytext}[1]{
\providecommand{\mytestinput}{#1}
\renewcommand{\mytestinput}{#1}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\mytestinput}{validate[a-zA-Z]}{}{\renewcommand{\mytestinput}{Defaultvalue}}
\textbf{#1}
}
```

In this case the command will work every time I compile and there is no way, that there is a wrong behaviour for the command.

Would that be a good idea?

Comment: You're using `\color` instead of `\textcolor`. Note that `\color{red}` is a declaration telling to start coloring text in red, whereas `\textcolor{red}{text}` will only color “text”.

Comment: You are right, have corrected the MWE.

Comment: What do you mean by “validate”? Checking if the input is characters only?

Comment: The first aproach is only to execute commands which can be executed if the corresponding package is loaded. This is my way to archive this.

The other question is, if I know the required input command (for example if I know, that only a-z and A-Z is allowed, and only 10 characters will be accepted not to destroy the layout of the document (for example) than it would be nice to prevent the input from any user....

Or otherwise (on argument will be passed as an option and there are only 5 options allowed (and if no one will be selected, default should be used automatically)...

Comment: Isn't this too much overhead? Couldn't you not just load (or `\RequirePackage` the relevant package?

Comment: I would think that this approach is good... Note though that you should typically check for package loads and subsequent conditioning `\AtBeginDocument` since [`xcolor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) might be loaded after your checking.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, you can do this, but if you do so, than you cannot decide the packageorder yourself. If you do this manually, than you have full control about the order of packages. Not doing this may result in conflicts...

But I will once more think about this (possible) solution.

Comment: @Werner good idea.

Any more suggestions are welcome...

Comment: The second question is still very vague. Testing for string length is perhaps okay, but composition may be difficult in general (unless you use regular expressions).

Comment: I was thinking about regex. Stringlengthtesting is ok. 

Is there any solution like 
\check{parameter}{regexsyntax}
.....true condition and false condition....

@Werner
I will submit a MWE in another question, so it is more clear....and wie can separate this two question to a new thread...

Comment: This should be executed at the end of the preamble anyway, so `\RequirePackage`, at this point, would not undermine the user's loading order because the package will only be loaded if the user has not included it at all.

Comment: vocabulary note:  i think you mean "achieve" (accomplish) instead of "archive" (preserve).

Comment: yes. You are right.

Answer (score 3):

Introducing `\setboolean{pkgldxcolor}{true}` and then testing that boolean serves no purpose, why not simply use

```
  \@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}
      {% do nothing
      }
      {% define \textcolor etc
      }
```

but in this case it seems you don't really need a test at all, you could `\usepackage{xcolor}` or if you do not want to force color to be loaded, just have

```
\providecommand{\textcolor}[2]{%
  Sorry, xcolor not loaded, you tried to make #2 in color #1}
```

which doesn't need to be guarded by a package loaded test as it will simply
do nothing of `color` is loaded and has defined `\textcolor`.

Comment: But the definition of `\test` does depend on the package loaded, doesn't it? In the non-debug case, it is supposed to print its argument in bold if colour is not available.

Comment: @cfr I'd just define `\test ` as  `\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}` always and just make the `\providecommand` of `\textcolor` handle the non color case, making it print text as above, or make a warning, or silently do nothing depending on requirements.

Comment: So would I: I just meant that this is a further feature of the original example. (I'm assuming it may be meant to do something not obvious from the minimal case, but maybe not.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
If I have serveral commands, which requires different packages than the boolean enables me to check different packagestates....

so if some more packages has to be added, all states can be gathered and used for the macros......

Think about the following....

package xcolor
Package longtable

on macro requires ONLY xcolor, the other one both....
So, my idea the first marco checks boolean xcolor only, the other one checks both wie \AND ....

Comment: @cfr you are absolutley right (first and third...comment)

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger you could have an and that worked with `@ifpackageloaded`, but as I say I can't think of many real use cases, certainly color and longtable are part of the core latex release so are always available, you can simply include them, if you do need a macro that depends on two packages that might not be there you can use `\providecommand` as I show to define stubs for all the commands you need.